# Powershell: Extract text from string using Regex

Tags: regex, string, powershell, text-extraction

I'm a complete noob when it come to regex, Can someone please help with this?

What I need is the domain, then I will need to replace all the (??) with a .

What I need Extracted: **(11)ops-findb01(13)domain(3)com(0)**

End result should look like: **.ops-findb01.domain.com.**

```
8/2/2012 3:37:59 PM 0908 PACKET  0000000002CC4F60 UDP Rcv 10.10.10.10  563a   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A     (11)ops-findb01(13)domain(3)com(0)
8/2/2012 3:37:59 PM 0908 PACKET  0000000002C32810 UDP Rcv 10.10.10.10  6f24   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A     (11)ops-findb01(13)domain(3)com(0)
8/2/2012 3:38:00 PM 0908 PACKET  00000000029EDC00 UDP Rcv 10.10.10.10  459a   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A     (3)www(6)google(3)com(0)
8/2/2012 3:38:00 PM 0908 PACKET  0000000002CC4F60 UDP Rcv 10.10.10.10  d47e   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR   (2)dr(7)_dns-sd(4)_udp(1)0(2)40(1)5(2)10(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
8/2/2012 3:38:00 PM 0908 PACKET  0000000002C32810 UDP Rcv 10.10.10.10  0b3c   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR   (2)db(7)_dns-sd(4)_udp(1)0(1)0(1)5(2)10(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
8/2/2012 3:38:00 PM 0908 PACKET  00000000029EDC00 UDP Rcv 10.10.10.10  8890   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A     (2)dl(6)javafx(3)com(0)
8/2/2012 3:38:00 PM 0908 PACKET  0000000002CC4F60 UDP Rcv 10.10.10.10  60e7   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A     (7)trading(9)scottrade(3)com(0)
```

***The log file format will always be what you see above***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming one line at a time:

`$betterline = ($line -match "\(\d+\)(?:\w+\(\d+\))+$") -replace "\(\d+\)", "."`

This first matches the line to grab the end part, then replaces the numbers and parentheses with a dot.

For the future, I strongly recommend you learn regex - it's simple yet invaluable. A great reference/tutorial for regex is [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help!!  Found 1 issue, should have been [\w-] because it needed to search for hyphen's.   See i'm learning :o)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that doesn't make extensive use of regular expressions:

```
Get-Content file.txt | Foreach-Object {

    #split the line by space
    $line = $_.split() 

    # get the last element and replace (one or more digits) with a dot
    $line[-1] = $line[-1] -replace '\(\d+\)','.' 

    #join the line back using a space
    $line -join ' ' # join the line back using a space

}
```